# supercsv how to get column value array by column name

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

Here is an example of csv file:

customerNo,firstName,lastName,birthDate,mailingAddress,married,numberOfKids,favouriteQuote,email,loyaltyPoints

1,John,Dunbar,13/06/1945,"1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
Mountain View, CA 94043
United States",,,"""May the Force be with you."" - Star Wars",jdunbar@gmail.com,0
2,Bob,Down,25/02/1919,"1601 Willow Rd.
Menlo Park, CA 94025
United States",Y,0,"""Frankly, my dear, I don't give a damn."" - Gone With The Wind",bobdown@hotmail.com,123456

**For exmaple, How can I get the all the column values belong to lastName?

I expect the result should be [Dunbar, Down].**
I've tried to search the doc, but could not find any useful example.

One more question is that, what's the meaning of getLineNumber() method? I've read the docu and it says "**Gets the current position in the file. The first line of the file is line number 1." But I am still confusing.**

Comment: you only want to get the last name from the csv ?

Comment: @NiksTyagi no, that's only the example for helping you understand what I am asking. I would like to get the array, containing the whole value of one column by input column name as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options. I've used CsvListReader, but you could just as easily use CsvMapReader or CsvBeanReader instead.

You could use the [Collector](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/cellprocessor/Collector.html) cell processor:

```
private static final String CSV = "firstName,lastName\nJohn,Dunbar\nBob,Down";

@Test
public final void testCollector() throws IOException {
    ICsvListReader reader = new CsvListReader(new StringReader(CSV), 
        CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
    reader.getHeader(true); // skip header

    // Collector processor 'collects' values from a column
    List<Object> firstNames = new ArrayList<Object>();
    CellProcessor[] processors = {new Collector(firstNames), null};

    while(reader.read(processors) != null){
        // just keep reading - Collector will collect the values
    }

    // prints: [John, Bob]
    System.out.println(firstNames);
}
```

Or grab the relevant column after Super CSV has read each line:

```
@Test
public final void testManual() throws IOException {
    ICsvListReader reader = new CsvListReader(new StringReader(CSV), 
        CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
    reader.getHeader(true); // skip header

    List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<String> line;
    while((line = reader.read()) != null){
        firstNames.add(line.get(0));
    }

    // prints: [John, Bob]
    System.out.println(firstNames);
}
```

Either way you'll need to read the whole file - CSV is not a spreadsheet and you can't just grab all of the values in a particular column easily (records can span more than 1 line!). Which brings me to your next question...

Straight from the javadoc:

[getLineNumber()](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/io/AbstractCsvReader.html#getLineNumber%28%29): Gets the current position in the file. The first line of the file is line number 1.

[getRowNumber()](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/io/AbstractCsvReader.html#getRowNumber%28%29): Gets the current row number (i.e. the number of CSV records - including the header - that have been read). This differs from the lineNumber, which is the number of real lines that have been read in the file. The first row is row 1 (which is typically the header row).

Answer (score 0):

If you can read each line of the csv e.g with readline, just split the string and read column 2.

```
String[] csvLine = getLine().split(",");  
String lastName = csvLine[2];
```

Comment: thanks, but if I could get the entire values of one column would be perfect. Like: [Dunbar, Down, Peter]

Comment: You could just loop and append. `lastName += ", " + csvLine[2]`

Comment: seems there is no method called getLine()

Comment: @user3112938:csv processing is line oriented. Check out this in case it helps http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_dozer.html

Comment: thanks, I just wondering if it is possible to be column oriented?

Comment: btw, do you know what's the meaning of getLineNumber? can't understand the value get from the example.

Comment: Means which line in your csv you are currently processing